# Safari not showing GREEN lettering for EV SSL

Tags: tls, certificates, web-browser, safari

I've recently installed an EV SSL cert on my server, Chrome and Firefox show a green banner and padlock denoting the EV cert is installed, but in Safari, it just shows a gray padlock... is there something extra I have to do for Safari to recognize that it's an EV cert? When I look at the certificate details in Safari it is the same certificate I see in Chrome and Firefox. I've cleared the browser cache several times and have restarted the computer. iOS Safari is showing gray as well in the title when it should be green.

Comment: Is Safari showing any errors or warnings related to the padlock?

Comment: Try running the Qualys ssl test ( https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/ ) to see if there's any potential issues with your certificate/deployment that Safari is picking up on.

Comment: Potentially relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14845177/https-displays-on-chrome-but-not-safari

Comment: It would be nice if we could find a description from Apple about what the gray padlock means. My google-fu is not finding my any documentation. Maybe in Safari's Help?

Comment: @drjimbob The SSL test shows an "A" for the overall rating

Comment: Did you end up getting a solution to this?

Comment: @mike... Nope, it just fixed itself...

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing some kind of error or warning from Safari, it's hard to tell exactly what's going on.

My best guess would be that your page contains some non-http content that Safari's not happy about [[link to StackOverflow post about this]](http://www.inmotionhosting.com/support/website/security/ssl-lock-display).

There seem to be some other things you can do wrong in the page code that Safari won't be happy about, for example using absolute references to content rather than relative [[link]](http://www.inmotionhosting.com/support/website/security/ssl-lock-display)

Comment: Nope.. not the problem, I always use relative links for internal content. As a matter of fact, Safari is now magically showing the "green bar" that it does and I have changed nothing. My guess is it must have been a caching issue somehow even though I cleared it several times, restarted the machine, and reset the P-ram.